# To what version of the kernel should I upgrade Mint 18.2 Xfce?

Tags: linux-mint, linux-kernel

I have some problems with my Linux Mint Xfce 18.2. Sometimes the wifi disconnects (an old Ubuntu bug with some wireless cards I think) and sometimes after (hybrid) sleep the fonts are messed up.

Before trying to fix the specific problems I was thinking about a kernel upgrade.

I know I can roll back to the present or even older versions of the kernel, Mint provides an easy way for that, but I wouldn't like to proceed by chance.

Where should I start?

[image]

[image]

I use 4.4.-81. Should I upgrade to the latest in the 4.4 series? To the latest in the Mint list? To the next up, or even the [latest](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/) possible? Downgrade maybe?

What are the factors to consider? I could provide various info on the laptop involved here, its components etc. What info should I provide?

---

EDITS:

```
~ $ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:5390]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company U98Z077.00 Half-size Mini PCIe Card [103c:1636]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
```

I have already (testing) selected the 4.11.0-14-generic.

Comment: What is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`?

Comment: @GAD3R: will add in question.

Comment: Try the `rt5390sta`  compile it with the current kernel https://github.com/agerwick/RT28XX-RT539X-Linux-driver (you can switch back to `rt2800pci` if it dosn't work properly  )

Comment: @GAD3R - Just running the program from the link left me with no wifi at all :) Could you give more details about that? Why to install it? Is it a recent driver for my Ralink? And how to switch back to rt2800pci if it dosn't work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the fact that security updates always go forward, I'll go as far as to state that you **should** update to the latest kernel update that you could use.

Having said that, use the kernel that works with the hardware you've got, probably in the 3.* series. The 4.* just seems too new to have all the bugs ironed out.

Then, add the non-free modules that your hardware demands and re-compile the kernel to use it.

Good luck.